# appFabric 1.1 Session Managment losing values

Tags: appfabric-cache, session-management, appfabric-beta-2

I am using appFabric 1.1 with windows 7 for Session Managment but it seems the Caching service is ignoring the Session Time ..

I dont see anything wrong on my web.config

Can someone give me a

allowLocation="true" 
        allowDefinition="Everywhere"/>

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried following steps in below url? I followed same steps and it is working for me.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh361711(v=azure.10).aspx